# Shorthand approach to inline conditional statement

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a form which is used for both create and update functionality. For the radio buttons i am trying to work an approach whereby a conditional statement is embedded in the html which checks the value from the database object and adds checked="checked" if it matches. The approach which i got to work is as follows

```
<input id="project-type-conditional-2" name="Project-Type" type="radio"  {% if scheme_item['Project-Type'] == 'A' %}checked='checked'{% endif %} value="A">
```

I was wondering if there is a better or more code efficient approach as current solution is a bit chunky.

Comment: What is the specific question?

Comment: I would suggest to tag more things like templating  django,flask etc not just python

Comment: Updated the question with a few tags and summarised my question if that helps.

Comment: You're not missing anything; your approach is perfectly valid Jinja2.

Comment: @jesseops thanks. I come from a ruby background so was thinking there may be a shorthand approach that isnt as wordy. If there's not so be it :)

Comment: As an aside I was looking into `print "checked='checked' if scheme_item['Project-Type'] == 'A' ` but was having difficulty with quotation marks output